# Flask TypeError: validate_on_submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: flask, typeerror

```
@app.route('/add_owner', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_owner():
form = AddOwner

if form.validate_on_submit():
    owner = Owner.name
    db.session.add(owner)
    db.session.commit()
```

I get an error at the if statement saying 'TypeError: validate_on_submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self''

Comment: Try this: ```form = AddOwner()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating object use () after the class name

```
form = AddOwner()
```